# SharePoint online About Me page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm new to O365 and using SharePoint Online. I want to be able to search for users profiles from the front UI and see a list of their attributes.

**i.e.** `Name`, `phone number` `department`, which `documents` they are working on etc.

When I search for users within sites, it pops up a page(`/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=bobby`) and clicking on `View Profile` sends me to Delve.

Also, Clicking on 'About Me' sends me to Delve.

**Is this the new way?**

**Is it possible to alter either delve or any other page to show what I want?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is how it works, Delve is the way to see people properties and see what common files they are working on.

Now there is nothing stopping you from creating your own display template for your people results page to show what ever data you'd like.

Here are a couple links to helpful information on getting started with display templates:
http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx

Comment: Hi Can Delve profile page be edited? Is Delve part of SharePoint Online ?

Comment: The delve page cannot be edited as it is in the layouts directory which we do not have access to and there is no UI option to edit it.

Comment: Hi Any hints on how to get started to display my own results page, any existing apps available for this?

Comment: updated with some useful links